# I want to give input to an input file type using my browser extension

Tags: browser-extension

chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "send_message", inputs: data ,files:files});

but using this code i can't send the filelist to the content script

please suggest me a way to either send or filelist how to give input to the input-file